# simple midi.js Player example

Tags: javascript, html, midi

I have been looking all over, but I can not seem to find a simple Player example for midi.js http://mudcu.be/midi-js/ .

The Player example is so complex I cannot get it to work in my page....What am I missing?

```
 <script src="./js/MIDI/AudioDetect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="./js/MIDI/LoadPlugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="./js/MIDI/Plugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="./js/MIDI/Player.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="./js/Window/DOMLoader.XMLHttp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <!-- extras -->
<script src="./inc/Base64.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./inc/base64binary.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
 MIDI.Player.loadFile("start.mid",MIDI.Player.start);
 MIDI.Player.start();

 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed some imports. For a midi player, you should use the `script` tags from the [demo-MIDIPlayer.html](https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/blob/master/demo-MIDIPlayer.html) file.

```
<script src="./js/MIDI/AudioDetect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/MIDI/LoadPlugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/MIDI/Plugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/MIDI/Player.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/Widgets/Loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/Window/Event.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/Window/DOMLoader.XMLHttp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jasmid package -->
<script src="./inc/jasmid/stream.js"></script>
<script src="./inc/jasmid/midifile.js"></script>
<script src="./inc/jasmid/replayer.js"></script>
<!-- extras -->
<script src="./inc/Base64.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./inc/base64binary.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, you need to load the plugin, before you can start playing a file.

```
window.onload = function () {
    MIDI.loadPlugin({
        callback: function() {
            MIDI.Player.loadFile("start.mid", MIDI.Player.start);
        }
    });
}
```